# could not generate APK on react native : :app:lintVitalRelease

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I create a key with this command :

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore first-key.keystore -alias first-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 1000
```

and add this to gradle file :

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('/home/mohamadreza/keys/first-key.keystore')
            storePassword '1234567890'
            keyAlias = 'first-key-alias'
            keyPassword 'qq-2012'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```

then I run this command:
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease

I got this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.4.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
...
```

my classpath :  classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2')

how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you find the answer:?

Answer (score 0):

This same issue I faced today.
I tried the following thing:

1. I deleted the output.json file from the folder
   "yourProject/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release".
2. And RUN command to build the application.

It worked for me.
Hope will work for you too